# Define multiple values in php-function and use them within functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Depending on the WordPress blog-URL, I need to define multiple variables (i.e. customer-group IDs). Some of the varaibles are integers and some are arrays. I want to use those variables in differnet functions within functions.php.

I need to know: is my solution good method, if I want to use multiple variables within different functions depending on the blog-URL?
I don’t want to use globals and constants don’t seem to work anymore in PHP-8 like they did in 7.2.

**Function I - blog URL:**

The variables change, depending on the blog URL. Function could look like this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_site_url' );
    function my_site_url(){
        $site_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
        
        $stage_url = 'https://los.examplos.mx';
        
        if ($site_url == $stage_url) {
            
            /* - customer group ids for use in functions */
            $wiederverkaeufer = 1234;
            
            /* Versteckte Kategorien */
            $hidecategory_wvk = [24, 863, 51, 87];

            $return_array = [$wiederverkaeufer, $hidecategory_wvk];
            
        } else {
            
            /* - customer group ids for use in functions */
            
            $wiederverkaeufer = 5678;
            
            /* Versteckte Kategorien */
            $hidecategory_wvk = [51, 48, 42];

            $return_array = [$wiederverkaeufer, $hidecategory_wvk];

        }
      return $return_array;
    }
```

**Function II**

Now I want to access those variables with some of the other functions within my functions.php. (This worked with constants before). For example

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cart_shipping_class_message', 20, 1 );
    function cart_items_shipping_class_message( $cart ){

    $my_ids = my_site_url();
    $my_ids[0] = $wiederverkaeufer;
        
    // Customer group current user 
    $group_id = BM_Conditionals::get_validated_customer_group();
    
    // if is group "wiederverkaeufer" return 
    if ( $wiederverkaeufer == $group_id )
        return;

    //Do something
}
```

**Function III: Test function:**

I built a little test-function to check if I can call multiple variables and arrays from one function.

```
 function my_shop_meldung(){
     
     $a = "Moin";
     $b = "Servus";
     $c = "Hallo";
     $d = ["22", "44", "55"];
     
    $return_array = [$a, $b, $c, $d];
     
     return $return_array; 
 }
 
 
 function add_custom_text() {
    ?>
    <div id="my_shopmeldung">
    <?php
        
        $my_results = my_shop_meldung();
        $a = $my_results[0];
        $b = $my_results[1]; 
        $c = $my_results[2];
        $d = $my_results[3][1];
        
        //echo $a . $b . $c . $d;
        echo $d;
        
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('kt_beforeheader', 'add_custom_text', 10, 0);
```

I think this works as I could see the output "44" from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

This function shows product categories in WordPress Woocommerce, depending on the "MarketPress" customer group. Please note: this example will work only if you use the plugin Marketpress.

**Function 1:**

```
//add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_site_url' );
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_site_url' );
    function my_site_url(){
        $site_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
        //$site_url = get_home_url();
        $stage_url = 'https://los.examplos.dk';
        $stage_url_2 = 'https://los.examplos.dk';
        
        //global $wiederverkaeufer, $hidecategory_wvk, $hidecategory_customer, 
        $boxkategorien, $gast_id, $kunde_id;
        
        if ($site_url == $stage_url || $site_url == $stage_url_2 ) {
            
            /* CONSTANTS - customer group ids for use in functions */
            $wiederverkaeufer = 11111;
            $gast_id = 22222;
            $kunde_id = 33333;
            
            /* Versteckte Kategorien */
            $hidecategory_wvk = [11, 22, 33, 44];
            $hidecategory_customer = [11, 22, 33, 44];
            
            /* BOXEN */
            $boxkategorien = = [11, 22, 33, 44];
            
        } else {
            
            /* CONSTANTS - customer group ids for use in functions */
            
            $wiederverkaeufer = 3333;
            $gast_id = 4444;
            $kunde_id = 5555;
            
            /* Versteckte Kategorien */
            $hidecategory_wvk = = [11, 22, 33, 44];
            $hidecategory_customer = = [11, 22, 33, 44];
            
            /* BOXEN */
            $box_kategorien = = [11, 22, 33, 44];];
        }
        
        $return_array = [
            $wiederverkaeufer,
            $gast_id,
            $kunde_id,
            $hidecategory_wvk,
            $hidecategory_customer,
            $boxkategorien      
            ];
        return $return_array;
    }
```

**Function II**
Hide Woocommerce product categories depending on MarketPress customer group.
Vustomer group identified via "$group_id = BM_Conditionals::get_validated_customer_group();"

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'exclude_cats_from_shop', 10, 3 );

function exclude_cats_from_shop($terms, $taxonomies, $args ){
    
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return $terms;
    $group_id = BM_Conditionals::get_validated_customer_group();
    //get the customer group ID of current user 
    $customer_group = my_site_url();
    //call function my_site_url(), get the array, and save to $customer_group
    $wiederverkaeufer = $customer_group[0];
    //save customer group id to $wiederverkaeufer

    $hidecategory_wvk = $customer_group[3];
    $hidecategory_customer = $customer_group[4];
    //get those product group ids
    
    if ( $wiederverkaeufer == $group_id ){
    //if wiederverkaeufer

        $new_terms     = array();
        //$hide_category_wvk = HIDECATEGORY_WVK; 
        // Ids der Produktkategorien die ausgeschlossen werden sollen

        if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && is_shop() || is_product() ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                if ( ! in_array( $term->term_id, $hidecategory_wvk ) ) {
                        $new_terms[] = $term;
                }
            }
            $terms = $new_terms;
        }
        return $terms;
        
    }// Ende ist Wiederverkaeufer
    
        // if is customer group customer 
    else {
        $new_terms     = array();
        // hide productcategories 
 
        if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && is_shop() || is_product() ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                if ( ! in_array( $term->term_id, $hidecategory_customer ) ) {
                        $new_terms[] = $term;
                }
            }
            $terms = $new_terms;
        }
        return $terms;
        } 
} //End
```